# Chrome on Mac hands off to Safari on iPhone

Tags: macos, ios, continuity

When I am using Chrome on my Mac (OSX Yosemite 10.10.2), it shows the handoff symbol on my iPhone. But when I open it, it hands off to Safari, not to Chrome on my iPhone (iOS 8.2).

How can I make **Chrome on my Mac hand off to Chrome on my iPhone**?

*On another note, when I use Chrome on my iPhone, it successfully hands off to Chrome on my Mac.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to open automaticaly another browser than Safari because Apple does not allow to set a custom browser as default on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably due to the fact that you cannot change your default browser in iOS.

Found this work-around, from [here](http://www.geekvulture.com/how-to-set-google-chrome-as-a-default-ios-browser/):

Method 2 : For all iOS users

Opening links in Google Chrome for iOS by default is also possible using a simple trick developed by Jon Abram called the iOS “Open in chrome” bookmarket. It is a small javascript code that a user needs to save in Safari bookmarks, tapping on this saved bookmark will transfer link to Google Chrome. The code is below.

```
javascript:location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4);
```

Instructions:

Copy the code above and bookmark this page in safari .
Now open safari bookmarks, click edit and edit the just saved bookmark .
Rename your Bookmark to anything like Open in chrome .
Delete the URL in the bookmark and replace it with the above javascript code.
Thats it!
Now your links can be opened in Google Chrome, if you open a link from within an app or email, it opens in safari, then hit the above bookmark to open it in chrome browser .
Any of the above methods can be used by a jailbroken user to set Google Chrome as default iOS browser while the regular users can